# Database Modeling vs Manually create Database with SQL instructions (Creating a DB for project)

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship

I am currently working on a project which include some "little" database, however I got into the question of "should I made the relational modeling of the db  and then export it into a sql query" or " should I manually create the database via sql instructions". since I've heard that creating db with frameworks (modeling) limits the db flexibility for further updates. however creating a DB on pure SQL instructions would allow me to do stuff much more easily.

Is that actually truth? or in the industry there is always a model?

Comment: Relational models and the use of an ORM framework for creating and handling databases are two different things. You can use a model without using a framework.

Comment: Are you talking about using the graphical interface of something like MySQL Workbench to create your model? Sorry I don't entirely understand the question.

Comment: Yes I am refering to that (mysql workbrench, enterprise architect etc) since I've seen projects where people don't have any model or anything where you can see the structure, they only begin with the sql coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice when creating a database would be to model what is required using a [Schema diagram](https://database.guide/what-is-a-database-schema/) first. That way you can easily change it around as required if you need to rework something and it is clear in your head what you are trying to achieve. So many times, people (myself in included) start coding things without it clear in their mind what they are trying to achieve and that makes the coding impossible. You can use software tools or pen and paper to create your diagram. Only when it makes sense in terms of the design should you start creating the database (Measure twice, cut once as the old saying goes)

In terms of creating the database, you can use code or a GUI (most products support both to my knowledge) and it is a matter of preference really.

I find writing the SQL code to be the best approach as you know exactly what is happening (GUIs can add things without your knowledge) plus you have a documented trail of what you have done in the form of an SQL script.

Not 100% sure if this answers what you asked but hopefully it helped

Comment: this actually answered my question, I really wanted to hear someone's opinion (when they start a project from scratch, or a database). plus you guided me to begin in the most suitable way for a project!, really appreciate your help.

Comment: no problem. Please click the tick icon to mark as the answer :)

Comment: oh, sorry I forgot about it ! ^^